# Why don't i have unlimited firebase resources in development?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Yesterday i ran into a problem with my android app. I thought the problem was in my code but after some debugging i found out that firebase shut off all my ressources and rights because i exceeded the quota. So my question is, is Firebase really limiting my ressources in development while not even deployed? Or is there a setting i missed that gives me no restrictions due to testing.

Anyway if my limit for the spark plan really is exceeded, do you have an alternative?
thanks

Comment: You can have local firebase for development. Their is no difference between dev and production. You still consume resource. It is was illimité in dev, be sure we could take advantage of it ;)

Comment: @TeddySmith Thank you very much! I didn't know local firestore existed. That's a big help. I already feared i would have to wait until next month to continue development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore has a daily free quota when you're on the Spark plan. That quota is enforced no matter what the status of your project is. If your daily usage goes beyond the free quota, requests will be blocked until the next day.

If you want to develop without hitting quota limits, you can use Firebase's [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite). These run locally on your machine, and have no quota enforcement.